# Одинаковая нумерация повторяющихся элементов списка

Tags: python, list

Есть список с повторяющимися элементами, мне необходимо пронумеровать этот список по порядку, но чтобы повторяющиеся элементы имели один и тот же номер.

Например:

`items = ["a","a","b","c","d","d","e","f"]` - Пример списка

`num =    1   1   2   3   4   4   5   6`  - Нумерация которую нужно получить

Comment: А для `["a","a","b","c","d","d","e", "b", "f", "a"]` будет `1   1   2   3   4   4   5  2   6 1`?

Comment: Ага, совершенно верно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если помнить какому элементу соответствует его индекс:

```
items = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "b", "f", "a"]

# Список для хранения индексов элементов
num_by_index = dict()

i = 1

for x in items:
    # Если элемент новый
    if x not in num_by_index:
        num_by_index[x] = i
        i += 1

print(num_by_index)  # {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'd': 4}

num = [num_by_index[x] for x in items]
print(num)  # [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 6, 1]
```